# How to search through TODO comment list in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, todo

I'm working on a huge project that has thousands of TODO items. So when I go to the TODO tool window in IntelliJ IDEA it shows all of them. How can I search for a specific one?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to define which TODOs should be found, you are able to set filter and patterns.

In TODO panel click on **Filter TODO Items** and select **Edit Filters**

[image: Intellij IDEA TODO Filter edit]

Here you are able to set filters and patterns which should be used. More about that is on their site https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/defining-todo-patterns-and-filters.html.
Keep in mind that after you define a new filter, Intellij will start with Indexing (long proccess for huge projects:( )

Also Intellij IDEA TODO tool lets you select from which part you want to see a TODOs (top bar on uploaded image) or you can simply show all TODOs and start typing (classic searching).

Comment: How come the various icons shown in the screenshot are more colorful than mine?

Answer (score 6):

First, expand all the todos (view the side menu or by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>numpad +</kbd>. Then just start typing, and IntelliJ will take you to the first place the string you searched for appears, be it a name of a folder, file or the text of the todo comment itself. Like any other search in IntelliJ, you can use the <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> keys to jump between items matching your search string.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a mac, keys ⌘6 (command key and number 6 key) will do the magic.

Answer (score 2):

Press `alt+6` to search `*TODO*` comment.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to view only the TODOs you have added in your current branch. You can use the Default Changelist tab for this:

[image]

The Scope Based tab also gives you some useful options for narrowing down the TODOs too:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not the *exact* answer to the given question, but it helped for me, so maybe it will also help someone else :)

What I haven't notice earlier is that TODO Tool Window/tab has some child tabs on the top. For me, the most usefull one, was the tab **„Current file”**. I was made aware of this feature after looking in official IDE documentation:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/todo-tool-window.html

Answer (score -1):

In the latest version of IntelliJ Idea(version 2023.2.1), you could use the 'TODO tool window'. The path is *View -> Tool Windows -> TODO*.

Comment: @PeterJ Yeah, you are right. I have edited it